# How to use sqlite command to import large CSV file?

Tags: linux, sqlite, csv, import

The problem is that the node that runs this needs more RAM than I have. The size of the final table should be around ~300GB.

```
sqlite>.import data.csv myTable

sqlite> CREATE TABLE DX (
                   id INTEGER,
                   data1 TEXT,
                   data2 INTEGER,
                   ...
                  );
```

Comment: What are you doing that requires the entire table to be held in memory?

Comment: That's normal and fine - unless you're running Sqlite in In-Memory Mode ( https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html ). What connection-string (or connection parameters) are you using? What error are you getting?

Comment: I am just creating the table from a csv file as shown above? I don't need it to be held in memory at all. What is the command to use in the linux 'sqlite3' app for it not to run in-memory?

Comment: You're not giving it the name of a file to use for the database? https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: @Shawn yea, now I am trying with the .open filename statement, it seems to be writing to disk, this could be the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shawn said, you just use:

```
.open filename
```

This creates the db on disk, and that's where the data will go when you import.